# Jquery hide() onclick before the page unloads

Tags: jquery, show-hide, onbeforeunload, onload-event

Hi i've been racking my brain for days. I'm creating a menu that drops down using the hide function in jquery. I want my menu bar to hide when my li tag is selected then the page navigates away to the next page in my site.

All that I get at the moment, when the anchor tag is selected, is that the menu just disappears.

This is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide(); 
    $(".show_hide").show(); 

    $(".show_hide").click(function(){ 
        $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle(); 
    });

    $(window).onbeforeunload(function() {
        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
});
});
```

This is the html:

```
    <div id="mobnav-wrapper">
    <div id="logo-top-mob"> 
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-mob.png" width="163" height="21" /></a>
    </div>

<div id="mob-button"> 
        <a href="#" class="show_hide"><img src="images/mob_button.png" width="33" height="24" /></a>

</div>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <ul> 
        <li class="hide_nav"><a href="work.html"> Work </a></li>
        <li class="hide_nav"><a href"services.html" >Services</a></li>
        <li class="hide_nav"><a href"clients.html" >Clients</a></li>
        <li class="hide_nav"><a href"about.html" >About</a></li>
            <li class="hide_nav"><a href"contact.html" >Contact</a></li>
        <li class="hide_nav"><a href"follow.html" >Follow</a></li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

I have tried to use the unload and .onbeforeunload but I can't get my head around it. If anyone has ideas or can point me in the right direction, I would be so so so thank full

Comment: Is there an artistic reason for wanting to hide the menu before you change the page? it appears you are not using ajax to load your contents, so as soon as someone clicks your menu links the browser will navigate to the next page.

Comment: It is artistic yes, I know that making a user wait till the next page reload is bad practise. I've thought it through and I think a short 2 sec close won't hamper the users experience but increase it.

Comment: Ok, youll find useful information on slideUp/slideDown, fadeIn/fadeOut, show/hide, etc here: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery functions `show()` and `hide()` are immediate. If you were intending to animate these elements, you need to add a speed argument:

```
$(window).onbeforeunload(function () {
  $('.slidingDiv').hide('fast');
});
```

That said, how much of your animation will actually run depends on how quickly the browser loads the next page from your server.

If you want your animation to run first, to completion, and *then* follow the link the user clicked, I would get rid of the onbeforeunload stuff and try something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.slidingDiv a', function () {
  var link = $(this);

  $('.slidingDiv').hide('slow', function () {
    location.href = link.attr('href');
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Amazing would never have to do this, Elliot Nelson you are the man. Two Thumbs up.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script to this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").hide(); 
    $(".show_hide").show(); 

    $("li.hide_nav a").click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = this.href;
        $(".slidingDiv").slideUp(500, function() {
            window.location.href = href;
        });
    });
});
```

It handles click events on the links in the `li` elements and firstly stops them from acting.  This means the `slideUp()` can execute and then run a callback function that handles the relocation that would have been triggered by the link click.